# Codeigniter 2.x - Authentication + ACL library

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I need a Codeigniter 2.x ACL + Authentication library.

I need to give have 3 different admin users and 2 different front end users and want to set everything dynamically through database.

Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two most popular authentication libraries for CI (at least as of early this year) seemed to be [Ion_auth](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/) and Tank_auth.  Neither handle your ACL needs, though Ion_auth provides single group functionality.

I started with Tank_auth on a project several months ago, but switched to Ion_auth when I needed more flexibility.  With it's included functionality, I added a user_groups table and the necessary library and model functions to allow multiple group memberships for each user.

The data structure:

```
mysql> describe auth_users_groups;
+------------+-----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                  | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+------------+-----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id         | int(11) unsigned      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| user_id    | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| group_id   | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| dt_updated | timestamp             | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+------------+-----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Some of the code added in the library:

```
   public function get_user_groups($user_id = NULL)
   {
      if ($user_id === NULL) $user_id = $this->get_user()->id;
      return $this->ci->ion_auth_model->get_user_groups($user_id)->result();
   }

   /**
    * is_member - checks for group membership via user_groups table
    *
    * @param string $group_name
    * @return bool
    **/
   public function is_member($group_name)
   {
      $user_groups = $this->ci->session->userdata('groups');

      if ($user_groups)
      {
         // Go through the groups to see if we have a match..
         foreach ($user_groups as $group)
         {
            if ($group->name == $group_name)
            {
               return true;
            }
         }
      }
      // No match was found:
      return false;
   }
```

Some of the model code:

```
   public function get_user_groups($user_id = NULL)
   {
      if ($user_id === NULL) return false;
      return $this->db->select('group_id, name, description, dt_updated')
                  ->join($this->tables['groups'], 'group_id = '.$this->tables['groups'].'.id', 'left')
                  ->where('user_id', $user_id)
                  ->get($this->tables['users_groups']);
   }

   public function set_group($user_id, $group_id)
   {
      $values = array('user_id'=>$user_id, 'group_id'=>$group_id);
       $hits = $this->db->where($values)->count_all_results($this->tables['users_groups']);
      if ($hits > 0)
      {
         return NULL;
      }
      return $this->db->insert($this->tables['users_groups'], $values);
   }

   public function remove_groups($user_id, $group_ids)
   {
      $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
      $this->db->where_in('group_id', $group_ids);
      return $this->db->delete($this->tables['users_groups']);
   }
```

Comment: Have you considered forking the project on GitHub and adding your functionality? It might be something the project is willing to merge in. It is a pretty straightforward addition that adds some good functionality.

Comment: @AndyShinn - While I still think Ion_auth is the best place to start, I've hacked it up to the extent it barely resembles the original.  I'll consider publishing it after my current project is done.  It now includes ACL, multiple email address capability, Mailchimp API integration, and considering FB/Twitter integration.  I'd need help cleaning it up and making the latter features optional, as they are simply "on" for the purpose of my project.

Comment: @MikeS. I'm using Ion Auth 2 and with that https://github.com/weblogics/Codeigniter-Ion-Auth-ACL plugin for Ion Auth 2. but I'm not getting how to give the permissions (key and value)? Will you help me to understand that code.

Comment: @GaneshAher, I forked Ion Auth over six years ago and haven't looked back. Sorry I can't be of assistance.

Comment: @MikeS. Ok, Thanks for reply.